# Как работает fastRoute?

Tags: php, router

Хотелось бы мне понять, как работает небезызвестный маршрутизатор fastRoute
[ссылка](https://github.com/nikic/FastRoute)

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

$dispatcher = FastRoute\simpleDispatcher(function(FastRoute\RouteCollector $r) {
    $r->addRoute('GET', '/users', 'Users/getUsers');
});
// Fetch method and URI from somewhere
$httpMethod = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

// Strip query string (?foo=bar) and decode URI
if (false !== $pos = strpos($uri, '?')) {
    $uri = substr($uri, 0, $pos);
}
$uri = rawurldecode($uri);
$routeInfo = $dispatcher->dispatch($httpMethod, $uri);

switch ($routeInfo[0]) {
    case FastRoute\Dispatcher::NOT_FOUND:
        // ... 404 Not Found
        break;
    case FastRoute\Dispatcher::METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED:
        $allowedMethods = $routeInfo[1];
        // ... 405 Method Not Allowed
        break;
    case FastRoute\Dispatcher::FOUND:
        $handler = $routeInfo[1];
        $vars = $routeInfo[2];
        // ... call $handler with $vars
        list($class, $method) = explode("/", $handler, 2);
        call_user_func_array([new $class, $method], $vars);
        break;
}
```

Класс Users и метод getUsers созданы. А дальше не могу понять что нужно делать? В браузере когда вызываю запрос вида http://example.com/users пишет что класс Users not found.
Просветите пожалуйста новичка!

Comment: Видимо вам нужно указывать пространство имен вместе с классом Users, чтобы composer знал, какой класс загружать. В composer'е, соответственно, это пространство имен должно быть зарегистрировано.

Comment: @Visman Спасибо вам! Добавил "classmap" в composer.json и сделал composer dump-autoload. Заработало.